# Invalid literal

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I just started coding about 4-5 weeks ago and am running into a few problems. I am trying to create a list high scores program. When I am trying to add a high score to the list I get the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10" I will post my code for you to look at. All and any help is awesome. Thank you!

```
scores = [("Roger", 1400), ("Justin", 2320), ("Beth", 3456)]

print("Hello! Welcome to the high scores!:")

print("\nHere are the current high score leaders!")
print(scores)

print("\n0 - Sort high scores")
print("1 - Add high score")
print("2 - Reverse the order")
print("3 - Remove a score")

print("Please enter your selection")

option = int(input())

if option == 0:
    scores.sort()
    print("These are the scores sorted alphabetically")
    print(scores)


if option == 1:
    print("Please enter your name and score; For example: Joe, 22")
    name, score =( int(input()), int(input()) )
    entry = (name, score)
    scores.append(entry)
    print(scores)
```

Comment: What programming language is that?  Please tag it.

Comment: `name, score =( int(input()), int(input()) )` When you enter a name like "Joe" as the first input there, Python is not going to be able to convert it to an int. Just get the raw input without the int conversion.

Comment: How would I go about getting it to convert? Would I take out the int code? @BilltheLizard

Comment: I tagged it @StephenC

Answer (score 0):

```
name, score =( int(input()), int(input()) )
```

Here, you get 2 inputs, and trying to convert both of them to integers. But,a name is not an integer. So, it should be

```
name,score = (raw_input(),int(input())
```

Comment: The raw_input function isn't being recognized by python and is telling me it is not defined. What am I doing wrong? @aswinmurugesh

Comment: @JustinFarr Just use the `input()` for the name and `int(input())` for the score.